# XHTML 1.1 Validataion Errors when Echoing Out XHTML Table?

Tags: php, html

I've created a PHP shopping cart using PHP & XHTML, a table of products is printed from a database in a table along with checkboxes. When validating the XHTML I get tho distinct errors a total of 48 times which are:

1) **Error Line 48, Column 136: document type does not allow element "form" here; missing one of "th", "td" start-tag**

```
…<form action="index.php" method="post"></form><td><div><fieldset><input type="…
```

2) **Error Line 48, Column 143: end tag for "form" which is not finished**

```
…ction="index.php" method="post"></form><td><div><fieldset><input type="checkbo…
```

and one single error at the bottom of the validation page

**document type does not allow element "fieldset" here**

```
…/></fieldset></div></td></tr><fieldset><p><input type="submit" name="sub" valu…
```

Here's my PHP:

```
else {
                    //echo "<center>";
                    echo '<div>';
                    echo "<table border='1'>
                    <tr>
                    <th>Manufacturer</th>
                    <th>Model</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Price</th>
                    <th>Add to basket</th>
                    </tr>";
                while ($get_row  = pg_fetch_array($get)) {

                    echo "<tr>";
                    echo "<td>" . $get_row['manufacturer'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $get_row['model'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $get_row['description'] . "</td>";
                    echo "<td>" . $get_row['price'] . "</td>";
                    //echo "<div>";
                    echo '<form action="index.php" method="post">';
                    echo '</form>';
                    //echo "</div>";
                    echo '<td><div><fieldset><input type="checkbox" name="selectedPhones[]" value='.'"'.$get_row['ref'].'"'.'/></fieldset></div></td>';
                    echo "</tr>";       


            }       echo '<fieldset>';
                    echo '<p><input type="submit" name="sub" value="Submit"/></p>';
                    echo '</fieldset>';
                    echo "</table>";
                    echo '</div>';
                    //echo "</center>";


           }
```

When I try to rectify them I cause more validation problems, can somebody show me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whoops! Moved the form elements outside of the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have  inside , that's it. Your code won't get valid.

But there's always a solution (as well as almost exactly similar questions): check up [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20273613/xhtml-1-1-validataion-errors-when-echoing-out-xhtml-table), it's one of Stackoverflow resolved cases.

Comment: Clever answer there. The link is recursive :)